# OpenCV GrabCut Algorithm example not working

Tags: opencv

I am trying to implement a grabcut algorithm in OpenCV using C++
I stumble upon [this site](http://www.packtpub.com/article/opencv-segmenting-images) and found a very simple way how to do it. Unfortunately, it seems like the code is not working for me

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
 // Open another image
    Mat image;
    image= cv::imread("images/mango11a.jpg");

    // define bounding rectangle 
    cv::Rect rectangle(50,70,image.cols-150,image.rows-180);

    cv::Mat result; // segmentation result (4 possible values)
    cv::Mat bgModel,fgModel; // the models (internally used)

    // GrabCut segmentation
    cv::grabCut(image,    // input image
                    result,   // segmentation result
                            rectangle,// rectangle containing foreground 
                            bgModel,fgModel, // models
                            1,        // number of iterations
                            cv::GC_INIT_WITH_RECT); // use rectangle
    cout << "oks pa dito" <<endl;
    // Get the pixels marked as likely foreground
    cv::compare(result,cv::GC_PR_FGD,result,cv::CMP_EQ);
    // Generate output image
    cv::Mat foreground(image.size(),CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
    image.copyTo(foreground,result); // bg pixels not copied

    // draw rectangle on original image
    cv::rectangle(image, rectangle, cv::Scalar(255,255,255),1);
    cv::namedWindow("Image");
    cv::imshow("Image",image);

    // display result
    cv::namedWindow("Segmented Image");
    cv::imshow("Segmented Image",foreground);


    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this please? What is supposed to be the problem
PS: NO errors were printed while compiling.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Are you sure your image is located in the right folder? And is your image larger than 150x180 pixels? Otherwise you are defining a rectangle outside your image regions.

Comment: Yes, my image is 930 X 700 and the image is in the right folders cause I have been using the same image for quite some time now. I tries printing on the command prompt and after the grabcut function call, cout does not seem to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

check your settings again. I just executed the same tutorial and it worked fine for me. [image]